# number of subsets of size k in a set with n subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Let N={{2,3,5}, {5,6,7} , {2,5,7} , {3,5,6}} and i want to know the number of subsets contained in N of size i conained in at least one of the subsets. For i=2 the result will be 8 ({2,3},{2,5} and {3,5} in the first subset, {5,6} and {5,7} and {6,7} in the second subset {4,7} in the third subset and {3,6} in the last subset). I dont realize how to exclude the combination already counted in a fancy way.

Thank you very much in advance,
Javier.

Comment: Look up the Stirling numbers of second kind.

Comment: Your terminology is very strange.  If N={{2,3,5}, {5,6,7} , {2,5,7} , {3,5,6}} the  {2, 3} is NOT a subset in N.

Comment: It seems to me that there likely isn't any clean solution other than brute force as it depends heavily on the overlap between the sets in $N$.  Also, as mentioned your terminology is off.  $\{2,3,5\}$ is an **element** of $N$, not a subset, and $\{2,3\}$ is a subset of an element of $N$, not a subset of $N$ itself.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I should use  "subsets of an element of N", sorry. I'll look the stirling numbers.

Comment: I dont think stirling number could be useful to solve my problem.